# Can any one explain the logic behind this code

Tags: python-3.x

Sorry for asking this very basic question - but I cannot understand why it does what it does.

```
a = int(input('Enter No. of rows'))
for i in range (a,0,-1):
  print(i*'*')
```

Thank you taking time to review and answer this question.

Comment: Please read [ask].  What don't you understand?  Have you read the [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) documentation?

Comment: Please clarify *exactly* what you don’t understand.  Have you tried debugging it, line by line, and breaking up each statement until you understand what *each* statement does?  If not, I’d recommend trying this.

Comment: Just to be clear, we are happy to help, and expect a concerted effort on your part, first.

Comment: Thanks to all.  I was not aware about the fact that  range function accepts three arguments.(start, stop, step) I will read documentation before asking anything next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `range` function accepts three arguments. The first arg. represents the starting integer, the second arg. represents the integer at which to stop, and the third arg. represents how much should the numbers increase by. Therefore, in this case, `(start, stop, step) = (a, 0, -1)`. This basically means start from `a` (the inputted value), move till `0` and increment by `-1`.

Then, in each iteration, the asterisk symbol (`*`), repeated `i` many times, is printed.

You can refer the range function [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Step by step.

In the first line you have:

```
a = int(input('Enter No. of rows'))
```

First you a have a variable, `a`, that's being attributed the `int` value of `input` from the user. Both `int()` and `input()` are functions.

That means that whatever number the user types will be cast to an int type and the result will be attributed to a variable called `a`

Then you have a for loop (See docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)):

```
for i in range (a,0,-1):
```

`for` loops are used when you have a block of code which you want to repeat a fixed number of times. It iterates over a sequence (either a list, a tuple, a dictionary, a set, or a string).

The syntax of a `for` loop is as such:

```
for <item> in <iterable>:
    <loop body>
```

So for each item in the iterable, the code inside the body of the for loop will be executed.

Then you have the `range()` function (see doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)). It takes 3 arguments: `range(<starting int>, <stopping int>, <step int>)`

`starting int`: integer starting from which the sequence of integers is to be returned

`stopping int`: integer before which the sequence of integers is to be returned.

`step int`:  integer value which determines the increment between each integer in the sequence

A negative step value in just means the `range()` function will generate the sequence of numbers in reverse order.

In the case of `range (a,0,-1)` it means the sequence of numbers returned from the `range()` function should start at the value of `a`, stop at 0 and decrease by 1.

Then in the last line you have:

```
print(i*'*')
```

The `(i*'*')` bit means that the string `'*'` should be printed `i` times on the console (check out [this](https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/answers/how-to-print-a-string-multiple-times-in-python#:%7E:text=Use%20range()%20to%20print,desired%20and%20print%20the%20result.) explanation).

Comment: Thank you. My understanding of range function in python is much better now.